# How can I parse xml from url in android?

Tags: android, url, xml-parsing

I am currently using a xml that has been downloaded and parsed from there. I would like to do it directly from the url itself. How can I do that?

I have added the snippet I am using below. Kindly help with a snippet or example.Thank you.

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
File file = new File(this.getFilesDir(), FILE_EXTRACTED);
Document dom = builder.parse(file);
Element root = dom.getDocumentElement();
root.normalize();
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use below Code for parse xml from url in android

```
public class XMLParsingDOMExample extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        /** Create a new layout to display the view */
        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
        layout.setOrientation(1);

        /** Create a new textview array to display the results */
        TextView name[];
        TextView website[];
        TextView category[];

        try {

            URL url = new URL("http://www.androidpeople.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/06/example.xml");
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

            NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");

            /** Assign textview array lenght by arraylist size */
            name = new TextView[nodeList.getLength()];
            website = new TextView[nodeList.getLength()];
            category = new TextView[nodeList.getLength()];

            for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {

                Node node = nodeList.item(i);

                name[i] = new TextView(this);
                website[i] = new TextView(this);
                category[i] = new TextView(this);

                Element fstElmnt = (Element) node;
                NodeList nameList = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("name");
                Element nameElement = (Element) nameList.item(0);
                nameList = nameElement.getChildNodes();
                name[i].setText("Name = " + ((Node) nameList.item(0)).getNodeValue());

                NodeList websiteList = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("website");
                Element websiteElement = (Element) websiteList.item(0);
                websiteList = websiteElement.getChildNodes();
                website[i].setText("Website = " + ((Node) websiteList.item(0)).getNodeValue());

                category[i].setText("Website Category = " + websiteElement.getAttribute("category"));

                layout.addView(name[i]);
                layout.addView(website[i]);
                layout.addView(category[i]);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("XML Pasing Excpetion = " + e);
        }

        /** Set the layout view to display */
        setContentView(layout);

    }
}
```

Comment: i don't kown if this will work since is not using an async task method

Answer (score 15):

My solution uses the code from the accepted answer however I found that it wouldn't work without using an AsyncTask

Here is my code, first I retrieve the XML and parse it in a method that uses an AsyncTask

```
public class RetrieveFeed extends AsyncTask {

URL url;
ArrayList<String> headlines = new ArrayList();
ArrayList<String> links = new ArrayList();
@Override
protected Object doInBackground(Object[] objects) {
    // Initializing instance variables


    try {
        url = new URL("http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml?edition=uk");

        XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setNamespaceAware(false);
        XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();

        // We will get the XML from an input stream
        xpp.setInput(getInputStream(url), "UTF_8");

        /* We will parse the XML content looking for the "<title>" tag which appears inside the "<item>" tag.
         * However, we should take in consideration that the rss feed name also is enclosed in a "<title>" tag.
         * As we know, every feed begins with these lines: "<channel><title>Feed_Name</title>...."
         * so we should skip the "<title>" tag which is a child of "<channel>" tag,
         * and take in consideration only "<title>" tag which is a child of "<item>"
         *
         * In order to achieve this, we will make use of a boolean variable.
         */
        boolean insideItem = false;

        // Returns the type of current event: START_TAG, END_TAG, etc..
        int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
        while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {

                if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("item")) {
                    insideItem = true;
                } else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("title")) {
                    if (insideItem)
                        headlines.add(xpp.nextText()); //extract the headline
                } else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("link")) {
                    if (insideItem)
                        links.add(xpp.nextText()); //extract the link of article
                }
            } else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG && xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("item")) {
                insideItem = false;
            }

            eventType = xpp.next(); //move to next element
        }

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

return headlines;
}


    public InputStream getInputStream(URL url) {
        try {
            return url.openConnection().getInputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

public ArrayList<String> heads()
{
    return headlines;
}
}
```

Then in the main activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    ArrayList<String> headlines = new ArrayList<>();

    RetrieveFeed getXML = new RetrieveFeed();
    getXML.execute();
    headlines = getXML.heads();


    // Binding data
    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, headlines);

    setListAdapter(adapter);

}
}
```

Make sure you have the correct uses permission in your manifest, put it inside the application tag but outside of any activity tags

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

and finally when extending ListActivity you ned to make sure you have a ListView in your main layout xml with the id:

```
android:id="@android:id/list"
```

Comment: İts better to use xpp.setInput(url.openConnection().getInputStream(), "UTF_8"); instead of xpp.setInput(getInputStream(url), "UTF_8");

Answer (score 5):

use this code .

```
public class XMLResourceDemo extends ListActivity {

private final static String TAG = XMLResourceDemo.class.getSimpleName();
TextView selection;
ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    selection = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.selection);

    try {
        XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();       
        factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser(); 
        xpp.setInput(new InputStreamReader(
            getUrlData("url")));

        while (xpp.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            Log.i(TAG, "doc started");
            if (xpp.getEventType() == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                if (xpp.getName().equals("entry")) {
                    items.add(xpp.getAttributeValue(0));
                }
            }
            xpp.next();
        }
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Request failed: " + t.toString(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items));
}

public InputStream getUrlData(String url) throws URISyntaxException, ClientProtocolException, IOException {

    DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet method = new HttpGet(new URI(url));
    HttpResponse res = client.execute(method);
    return res.getEntity().getContent();
}
```

Comment: Can I make any changes to the above snippet which I have given to call url for parsing..

Comment: by using above code you can get xml document from the Url from that you can parse xml.