# Android retrieved XML, how to populate SQLite?

Tags: android, xml, sqlite

My app calls a web service and receives a set of data in xml format. How can I populate a database then?

```
<NewDataSet xmlns="">
          <Country>
            <ID>0001</ID>
            <Type>Country</Type>
            <Code>IN</Code>
            <Description>India</Description>
            <IconName>IN</IconName>
            <IconURL>http://.../IN.jpeg</IconURL>
          </Country>

<Country>
            <ID>0002</ID>
            <Type>Country</Type>
            <Code>FR</Code>
            <Description>France</Description>
            <IconName>FR</IconName>
            <IconURL>http://.../FR.jpeg</IconURL>
          </Country>
</>
```

Should I store retrieved data as xml file or somehow immediately push it to SQLite?

Comment: no, I'm asking where should I store retrieved data before parsing? as an xml file in assets folder?

Comment: The example at jcaruso's link uses an input stream. There is no need to store the XML data in a file. Just parse right away. The for loop iterates through the queried XML elements.

Answer (score 0):

Your going to have to parse the XML data and them loop through it to insert it into sqlite.

Try this as for your XML paring: [How can I parse xml from url in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12065951/how-can-i-parse-xml-from-url-in-android)

Then if you have you Content Provider set up call it to do your inserts.

Comment: Should I store retrieved data as xml file in assets folder before parsing?

Comment: @IvanFazaniuk IMHO I don't see the need to do so.