# Get Array from XML file stored in url

Tags: java, android, json, xml

I am trying to get all arrays I store in: https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/tekstpieprz/strings.xml

I would like to use them for my textviews. I have added Unirest but cannot get my head around JSON. I have tried to play with something like:

```
HttpResponse<JsonNode> request = (HttpResponse<JsonNode>) Unirest.get("https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/tekstpieprz/strings.xml")
            .getBody("docukrz");
    JSONObject myObj = request.getBody().getObject();
    final JSONArray results  = myObj.getJSONArray(String docukrz);
```

so then I can use the array in:

```
    final String[] docukrz = res.getStringArray(R.array.docukrz);
```

But instead using

> Resources

I would like to use the array I store online.
I do not fully understand how JSON works, I have only started learning JAVA 6 weeks ago. Any help would be much much appreciated.

Comment: The response is in XML, not JSON. You need to use an XML parser.

Comment: But how? Honestly wherever I ask I cannot find a simple answer. I have searched a lot on stack and other forums and everyone is suggesting something else. I have been suggested to use Unirest, retrofit, xml parse. I am just learning this stuff and I honestly don't know where to learn from. I may as well just keep the resources file locally, but I thought I will go step forward and put it online, so I can change it whenever I want without new app version. Would appreciate some more details or at least to point where I could begin or where to learn from. Thanks!

Comment: Online resources are a bad idea. What if the device is offline?

Comment: Then it won't work, simple as that. I will be updating the file frequently plus I have spent so much time on it I would like to know how to do that for future. Sorry but your comment does not help.

Answer (score 1):

You can find XML prase example here [How can I parse xml from url in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12065951/how-can-i-parse-xml-from-url-in-android).
 according to that answer, your code should be like below

```
   URL url = new URL("https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/tekstpieprz/strings.xml");
     DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
     DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
     Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
     doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

     NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("docukrz");
     ArrayList resourceList = new ArrayList();
      for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {

          Node node = nodeList.item(i);
          resourceList.add(node);
 }
```

Comment: If another question has the same answer, you should mark as duplicate, not copy the answer.